# How to get values from org.mozilla.NativeArray in Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, scriptengine

I'm using ScriptEngine with **rhino** as the engine name to evaluate javascript in Android. The javascript code that I evaluate looks like this :

```
var course_data = [];
course_data[0] = [];
course_data[0]['course_name'] = 'Programming 101';course_data[0]['course_code'] = 'XXX12345';course_data[0]['course_credit'] = '2';
course_data[1]['course_name'] = 'Next Level Programming';course_data[0]['course_code'] = 'XXX12356';course_data[0]['course_credit'] = '3';
```

The ScriptEngine get("course_data") method return org.mozilla.**NativeArray** object. I can't use org.jdk.Nashorn.api.scripting.**ScriptObjectMirror** since NativeArray can't be converted to ScriptObjectMirror.

How do I get each course_data course name, code, and credit value from this NativeArray object?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What have you tried yourself or researched? Did you check the docs, e.g. https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray.html?

Comment: I solved my problem. It turned out to be NativeArray inside NativeArray. I use ScriptableObject to get each array from the main array. I did check the docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use ScriptableObject to get each NativeArray inside the main NativeArray.

```
ScriptableObject data = (ScriptableObject) engine.get("course_data ");
for(int j=0;j<data.size();j++){
    NativeArray courseArray = (NativeArray) data.get(j);
    String courseName= courseArray .get("course_name").toString();
    String courseCode= courseArray .get("course_code").toString();
    int courseCredit= Integer.parseInt(courseArray .get("course_credit").toString());
    System.out.println(courseName+" "+courseCode+" "+courseCredit);
}
```